# Bluetooth not working, qualcomm QCNFA335

Tags: bluetooth

So, just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and it says:

```
Bluetooth adapter not found
```

I have QCNFA335 Wifi/bluetooth card. Wifi DOES work. Updating drivers doesn't help, since there are no drivers for it in the repository.
lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c81 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb`